# Trying to send a variable in the HTML a tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send through the code

```
    $abfrage = "SELECT nummer,vorname,nachname,adresse,tel,fax,email,website 
FROM kontakte";

    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
    {

    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><a href="./test.php?Id=$row[nummer]">Edit</a></td>
```

the id to the test.php file, which is:

```
<?php
include("./scripts/cn.php");

$testvar=$_GET['id'];

echo "$testvar";
?>
```

but i just get a notice: "Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4"

Why does my test.php recieves no id? 
i was trying to use

```
<td><a href=\"test.php?Id=$row[nummer]\">Edit</a></td>
```

But my there is a problem with "%22" through rederecting to test.php.

Comment: Do you have PHP outputting `<a href="./test.php?Id=$row[nummer]">`? I don't see any in your code, and if you don't then that text will be sent to the browser, not the output that you want.

Comment: test.php is kind of supposed to output the id, but i'm not sure, because i'm new to php (test.php is the second part of the code)

Comment: You shouldn't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore. Use the `mysqli` extension or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this

```
$row->nummer
```

Instead of

```
$row[nummer]
```

Since php tag is closed use like this

```
<td><a href="./test.php?Id=<?php echo $row->nummer ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the browser is now getting the id.

Comment: Could you help me with catching the id and using it i my script? $_GET i kind of not working for me -.-

Comment: all case sensitive here, use same `Id` or `id` in both html and php